# handbreak does not extract subtitles

Tags: video, handbrake, transcode

i have a personal DVD i am trying to backup to a medium that will not go the way of the 5" floppy...

when i "rip" it via handbreak, i select subtitles, then i click "add all" and the subtitle does show up as `1 - English (VOBSUB) -> passtrhoug`.

then i hit Start and the final m4v (i am using the default "high" profile, nothing changed besides adding all subtitles) ends up with a single subtitle track. but when i enable it and play the file on vlc, all i get for subtitles is "Chapter 1"...

nothing of the original subtitles. Playing the DVD on vlc and selecting the only subtitle channel, i do get the right text.

what do i have to do on handbreak to include the subtitle correctly?

Comment: There are many different methods for subtitles on DVD's and different ways you need to rip them with the video, what type of subtitle does the DVD have?...https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Subtitles

Comment: i did more tests... if i use the exact same profile but change the encoding to matroska. the subtitles work. if i leave m4v, then the subtitle track after encoding only contain the Chapter name and nothing else... let me try to encode m4v without chapters

Comment: yep, doesn't matter the video encoder. If i include chapter marks, then the first (and only) subtitle track becomes nothing but the chapter names! if i disable chapter marks and leave absolutely everything else the same, i get subtitles. I will probably close this one out as it is probably a bug in my distro's version of handbreak